# Not reading ~/.vimrc

Tags: vim

I have a ~/.vimrc file that vim doesn't seem to be reading.
There is a file at /etc/vimrc, and it looks like it is using that one.

My understanding is that the one in the home directory should override this one, shouldn't it?

**Update**

```
cat vim_strace | grep .vimrc
    stat64("/etc/vimrc", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1438, ...}) = 0
    open("/etc/vimrc", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
    stat64("/etc/vimrc", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1438, ...}) = 0
    stat64("/root/.vimrc", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=35, ...}) = 0
    open("/root/.vimrc", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
    stat64("/root/.vimrc", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=35, ...}) = 0
```

Comment: They're both run. `/etc/vimrc` should be loaded first, then `~/.vimrc` should be loaded. There are a few other things loaded, most of which are contained in your `~/.vim/` directory. Don't know why yours isn't loading.

Comment: I modified the question to include the strace output...

Does the root folder vimrc override the settings in /etc/vimrc?

Comment: Do you mean to use /root/.vimrc or do you want to use /home/ninjacat/.vimrc (or similar)?

Comment: Well, for this user, /root/.vimrc is fine.  I haven't played with the other user yet.

Comment: /root/.vimrc is what ~/.vimrc means in your situation (which you haven't described in the question), check the HOME environment variable (printenv HOME or echo $HOME).  If you want ~/.vimrc to mean something else (i.e. /home/.../.vimrc), then you need to change something outside of vim.

Comment: In other words, vim *is* reading ~/.vimrc, but ~ means /root and it seems you didn't expect that.

Comment: apparently, my vim version 8.x on cygwin is looking in `~/.vim/vimrc`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

if you're on linux and want to know if vim is accessing your ~/.vimrc on startup you can launch it with strace:

```
strace -o vim_strace vim
```

then quit vim.
Open the vim_strace file and search for "vimrc" in the file. you should find a line like that

```
stat64("/home/youruser/.vimrc", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

which mean that at least vim sees the file.

Comment: This is a slick way of figuring this out.

Comment: Note that some virmrc files are not in your home directory. I'm running Raspbian, and mine was in `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`.

Comment: I wish I new about the strace command years ago. This is extremely useful; thank you.

Answer (score 148):

Once you've loaded vim, `:scriptnames` will tell you exactly what Vim read.

For me, it starts like this:

```
  1: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
  2: ~/.vimrc
  3: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

IF you want to check where a particular setting is being set, use "verbose set". For example, `:verbose set background` tells me:

```
  background=light
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

so I know that my setting in ~/.vimrc is being read, and that none of the later files is clobbering it.

Comment: This was useful +1. Unfortunately, for some reason, although syntax.vim shows up on my `scriptnames` it's still the only command in my vimrc not getting read or showing up in the `:verbose set`, any ideas?

Comment: This is helpful but does not solve the problem. Now I know ~/.vimrc has not been read, but why is that happening?

Comment: Maybe look at `:h MYVIMRC` for more information how vim reads his configs.

Comment: `scriptnames` tells me that there are 24 files being read - mostly from my \vim82\ installation directory. Why so many? I thought it just reads one VIMRC file??

Answer (score 48):

If anyone happen upon this issue while using [**neovim**](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) you should know (before you start pulling off your hair) that the `.vimrc` file is loaded from `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim; ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

Comment: Note, you can simply add `source ~/.vimrc` in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` to  source configs without relying on symbolic links.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This has helped me.

Comment: This help me too

Comment: Good to know this caveat for NeoVim. This helped me (accepted answer was not useful as I saw ~/.vimrc in the trace of vim, but vim was not loading it). Thanks!

Comment: you mean init.lua

Comment: Thanks. This was much needed. I was struggling until I found this solution.

Answer (score 24):

I had this problem and just added the following to the file `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias vim="vim -S ~/.vimrc"
```

Comment: The real question is why do you have this problem (and me as well)

Comment: This could happen if you're really using neovim but have it aliased to vim

Comment: I have neovim and have a symbolic link for vim (probably should've aliased), and had this problem.  GuestUser123456789's solution fixed it.

Comment: Since this answer is attracting **NeoVIM** users:
Your default config is at `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`
Please add `source ~/.vimrc` to render the `.vimrc` settings.

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone else runs across this issue, and like me realizes .`vimrc` wasn't read because of sudo, try using `sudo -E`. It retains your environment for the command, and `$HOME` will point to your own home dir. Note this may not work in environments where `/home` is mounted with *rootsquash*.

Comment: THANK YOU! `sudo - E` didn't work for me, but I just changed the color scheme for the root user as well:-)

Comment: This worked for me. Note that there is no space between `-` and `E`, but even if `-E` doesn't work, copying your own `.vimrc` file to `/root` also does the trick!

Comment: Thank you so much. Every time that bell went off it was like a little sledgehammer to my frontal cortex.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add on hellvinz's instruction.

After you have made vim_strace file.

```
cat vim_strace | grep .vimrc
```

makes life bit easy :)

Comment: `grep .vimrc vim_strace` is even better.

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled on this post and non of the suggestions worked for me. Some useful things not mentioned here:

1. vim --version should give you some useful info including the startup files. (Mine listed "virc" in several places (not vimrc)
2. If your vim isn't really vim then perhaps it is looking for ~/.exrc instead of .vimrc (Mine looks for some system vircs, then some users vircs and then $HOME/.exrc)
3. If your file (whichever one it is) has DOS line endings it may cause errors

... so even though I've got a real vim, it's looking for "virc"

Comment: Yes, vim --version on CentOS 7 shows these locations:
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"

Answer (score 3):

On OSX 10.8.0 the location of the vimrc file is:  /usr/share/vim/vimrc

I just add my changes to the bottom of the file.

Of course this has the effect of making the changes for all users.  For the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to get it to read ~/.vimrc.  This was never an issue for me on 10.6.x

Anyway this is a quick fix even it is a bit dirty.

Comment: 10.8? I'm on 10.7.3 in 2012... I want to know how you got to 10.8 last year.

Answer (score 3):

use file **/etc/vim/vimrc.local**  in Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Check if `$VIMINIT` has been set. It may prevent reading your `~/.vimrc`. See `:help VIMINIT`:

```
 c. Four places are searched for initializations.  The first that exists
    is used, the others are ignored.  [...]
    -  The environment variable VIMINIT [...]
```

For me unsetting `VIMINIT` did the trick, my `~/.vimrc` is now read.

Answer (score 3):

After checking `scriptnames` and `verbose` as suggested above, I noticed that my setting was indeed being loaded, but being overridden by another plugin, thus giving the impression that it was not reading/loading the `.vimrc`.

If this happens to you and you want to override a specific setting from a plugin, without completely eliminating all the other good things that come from that plugin, you can create a config file to load **after** the plugin is loaded, by creating a file in `~/.vim/after/<path>/<plugin_name>`. For reference, see [this other question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/when-to-use-the-after-directory).

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/vim/vimrc` is now overwritten by defaults.vim unless there is a `~/.vimrc`, apparently.
https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2042

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with vim 8.1.3741 on Kubuntu 20.04

It seems the problem was that the ~$/.vimrc file was starting with a long comment starting with " and went over 2 lines (autobreak) The vim_strace showed input 133 and wrote the comment out but not the command under it. Removing the comment worked. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the mistake was I had the configuration set at `~/.vim/.vimrc`.
After reading some documentation, I found that right path is `~/.vim/vimrc`.

Changing the file did the trick.

Comment: This was it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR check that you don't have any inline comments in your .vimrc

After all of the helpful answers under this question I was still stuck. My `~/vimrc`

```
set mouse-=a
set tabstop=4     " Indents will have a width of 4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4 " Sets the number of columns for a TAB
set expandtab     " Expand TABs to spaces
syntax on
set paste
" set compatible
set t_ti= t_te= "stop ^z clearing the screen
" remember line
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
" unless gitcommit
autocmd FileType gitcommit call setpos('.', [0, 1, 1, 0])
```

was located by vim and strace showed that it was read. Turns out that vim.basic on my system seems to ignore the **entire line** *if* it contains a comment. (So inline comments disable settings on the same line.)

I moved the "Expand TABs to spaces" comment to the previous line and instantly `expandtab` showed up the next time I ran `vim -c :set`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using Vim on Parrot. I realised that I was using the regular **MATE terminal** when I used `sudo vi ~/.vimrc`.
I would suggest for this edit, use **Root Terminal** and run the command again.
This will work for all distros.