# Xdebug trace vim syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, xdebug, trace

I'm trying to get the [vim syntax file](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/contrib/xt.vim) for [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace#othersettings) installed.

First I placed the file (`xt.vim`) in the `~/.vim/syntax` directory. Opening a `.xt` file, there was no highlighting. I found a [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9700719/680920) on a related thread.

With the file opened in vi, I ran `:scriptnames`; the `~/.vim/syntax` directory was not listed at all, however I did see some entries for `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax` with a few `.vim` files in it. I then moved `xt.vim` to this directory and changed perms to match the other files, yet still no syntax highlighting when opening an `.xt` file.

The name of the file I'm trying to open is `/tmp/trace.2043925204.0c00ca.xt`, I tried renaming it to `/tmp/trace.xt` to no avail. What must I do to get this syntax file properly installed?

Comment: Enable syntax in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: First line of my `.vimrc` - `syntax on`