# Vim not showing numbering on side

Tags: vim

Hello and thanks in advance for looking over this.

I recently reset all of my settings for vim. I went back to edit the now empty .vimrc with numbering and it isn't working. Here's what I did:

```
vi ~/.vimrc
set number
set relativenumber
```

However no numbering appears in my vim editor. Any suggestions? Thank you for any help.

**UPDATE**
Solution found at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495124/not-reading-vimrc) to solve the problem. Was using neovim for setup and it caused my init file to be empty

Comment: What is the output of `:verbose set number?`  ?

Comment: What if you just run `:set nu` within a vim buffer?

Comment: :set nu works and so does :verbose set number

Comment: @Scott.F first you need to open Vim, then enter the command. Typing `:verbose set number?` in the shell will return "command not found"

Comment: @Sergio yeah I realized my stupid mistake about a second after the reply. I get nonumber as the response from the command

Comment: `:verbose set number?`  should print the file name where the option `number` was last set. For example: `Last set from ~/.vimrc`.

Comment: All im getting from it is nonumber so I'm guessing its not getting set for some reason from the .vimrc

Comment: What does your .vimrc actually look like?  Did you put `set number set relativenumber` all on one line?

Comment: They're on separate lines. It appears as set number \n set relativenumber just the text for the question all appeared on one line

Comment: Maybe your .vimrc isn't getting loaded for some reason.  What if you open something with `vim -u ~/.vimrc`?

Comment: The numbering appears when I use that and verbose tells me its from the .vimrc

Comment: Okay, so we've established the .vimrc is good.  What if you just open vim normally?  And I mean running with the full name `vim` and not `vi`.

Comment: I tried both just now just to make sure and both seem to not load the .vimrc

Comment: Maybe this question will apply to your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495124/not-reading-vimrc

Comment: Thanks for linking that. Im gonna mark this as a duplicate. Finally reconnected the setup to nvim as I realized it was relying on neovim for the setup and it worked. Thank you @ChristianGibbons for your help and time

Comment: Thank you also @Sergio for your time and help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not reading ~/.vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495124/not-reading-vimrc)